# SQL query to return count of monthly rows is slow

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

So, the original query was quite simple.

```
select MONTH(DateColumn), COUNT(DateColumn)
from myTable
where YEAR(DateColumn) = '2014'
group by MONTH(DateColumn)
order by MONTH(DateColumn)
```

But, one of the months didn't have data, and I need to have all 12 months covered. So I'm busy reworking it.. I have a solution, but it is painfully slow. There must be a better way.

```
select o.MonthCount, coalesce(d.total,0) from (
select top 12 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 12)) as MonthCount from myTable
) o outer apply (
select month(e.DateColumn) as mon, COUNT(e.DateColumn) as total
from myTable e 
where YEAR(e.DateColumn) = '2013' 
and o.monthcount = month(e.DateColumn) 
group by MONTH(e.DateColumn) 
) d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table with the 12 months in it and left join with the result of the first query. Something like:

```
;with cte as (select 1 as m
union select 2
union select 3
union select 4
union select 5
union select 6
union select 7
union select 8
union select 9
union select 10
union select 11
union select 12)
select cte.m, ISNULL(m.c, 0)
from cte left join (
select MONTH(DateColumn) mon, COUNT(DateColumn) c
from myTable
where YEAR(DateColumn) = '2014'
group by MONTH(DateColumn)) i on i.mon = cte.m
order by cte.m
```

Comment: Awesome! that worked quite well.. One odd thing, it can give null for a count, and neither isnull or coalesce on count(DateColumn) will change it to 0. But I should be able to fix that at the app level.

Comment: Ah! wait.. I figured out. I was putting it in the inner left join instead of in the outer select query.. First time using cte's.. Either way thx! (took a query that was about 3min to 3s..)

Comment: @Caimbul I updated select part of the answer, is that what you meant? 3mins to 3 secs sounds good.

Comment: Yup.. that's it. Thanks!